# Embed all fonts by "exporting as PDF", but cannot copy text any more?

Tags: fonts, copy-paste

I am using `Fontin` as the font style and `XeLaTeX` my document. In order to ensure every computer can display the font style correctly, I decided to re-export the document as PDF with Mac Preview so that all the fonts are embedded in itself (this trick indeed works!).

However, a new problem arises. In the re-exported PDF file, once I copy the text, many spaces are copied. But I can copy text in my original PDF file.

How can I fix this? Being able to copy text from my document is as important as embedding all the fonts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle with Mac Preview. Sincerely sorry for the confusion caused!

Comment: Exporting from Preview, while doing this nasty thing, will not embed the font completely. If I ask for the font properties of the exported file in Adobe Reader, it says “Fontin (embedded subset)”.

Comment: Why do you want to embed the fonts fully? An embedded subset should be enough to ensure the file displays correctly, shouldn't it?

Comment: @cfr I am sorry, maybe I have wrongly touched the jargon. What I need is just to make sure the file be displayed correctly.

Comment: @egreg I am sincerely sorry for the confusion caused. As long as I am 100% sure my file font can be displayed correctly, I am good. So maybe I shouldn't have said "all the fonts".

Comment: If you view the properties of the file in your pdf viewer, it should show you whether the fonts are being embedded by the compilation process or not. Or you can use `pdffonts` on the command line (at least on Unix-like systems). Check first if there is a problem. If there is, address the problem by figuring out why fonts are not being embedded and taking steps to ensure that they are.

Comment: @SibbsGambling have you solved this yet? The default behavior (embedded subset) should allow you to view the document on any system with no issues; if that is not the case for you, we'll need minimal code to reproduce and potentially some information about your computing environment.